# How to integrate youtube in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, integration, youtube-data-api

i want to integrate youtube in my app. and show video in table view can anybody help me.
please give me details in steps how to integrate youtube and show videos list in tableview or can i download these videos on button click.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: Check This Link  It is Help full For u http://www.appcoda.com/youtube-api-ios-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to use pod to integrate youtube in your app.

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git =>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
```

Its official way to use youtube in it. Give it try, you don't need to write html and css yourself.

**Sample Usage**

1) Add `UIView` in xib and change its class to `YTPlayerView`

2) Create IBOutlet for `YTPlayerView`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;
```

2) In `ViewController.m`

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                                     @"playsinline"    : @1,
                                     @"showinfo"       : @0,
                                     @"rel"            : @0,
                                     @"controls"       : @1,
                                     @"origin"         : @"https://www.example.com", // this is critical
                                     @"modestbranding" : @1
                                     };

 [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"Youtube Video Id" playerVars:playerVars];
```

For complete documentation please visit.
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

For Detailed tutorial provided by `Youtube`
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#installation

Comment: Good answer..thanks but can you provide some code to authentication for your before using youtube. and all api that are required to get videos , authentication or for download...

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

You can integrate it by cocoa pod.You can show it in UITableView.

You can't download youtube videos directly from youtube.